# Change encryption algorithm in AWS Cognito access token JWT

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, encryption, jwt, amazon-cognito

When I used [the sample code](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cognito-java-desktop-app) provided by aws, access token is encrypted with RS256 as below

> {   "kid": "hPkzClOPlyg092q+pE4eWdfyWEHi0q9ZMGtxukeawzk=",   "alg":
>   "RS256" }

How do we change it to some other value like RS512? I have replaced values `HmacSHA256` with `HmacSHA512`. But that did not change algorithm values to RS512.

Comment: even though this is an old question: this is about signature, not encryption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html, Cognito always uses the RS256 algorithm for JWT tokens it creates (and it cannot be changed).